Movie about someone (Robin Williams?) getting hired to do comedy in the Muslim world
The movie's about USA government hiring Robin Williams to do comedy in the Muslim world. His destination was Pakistan but due to some problems, he makes it to india instead and does a comedy show there. He tries to get across the indian border to pakistan but is unsuccessful. This raises the security tension so that he's escorted back to USA for his safety.
Apparently he did all this to get some kind of a reward that the government gives out. He never received it. Also he brings his son a Christmas present when he gets back home.
Can anyone tell me what the name of this movie is?
I checked the Robin Williams wiki and IMDB and yet I don't see this one movie there.

The reason you didn't find is probably because it features Albert Brooks, not Robin Williams. I ran a google search for "movie india pakistan islam comedian" and found this:
Looking for Comedy in the Muslim World:

To improve its relations with Muslim countries, the United States government sends comedian Albert Brooks to south Asia to write a report on what makes followers of Islam laugh.

and 

The American senate, in order to improve it's fast declining global image, asks comedian Albert Brooks to write a 500 page document about what makes Muslims laugh in India and Pakistan.


+1: Nice find. Let that be a lesson to all about including actor's names in questions if you're not 100% sure!

Wow. That's the one.  I can't believe I confused Robin Williams with Albert Brooks. That's crazy.

@AndrewMartin ... I'd bet he was sure at the time of writing the post ... :-)
